# Using Confluent KafkaAvroSerializer library

Tags: avro, confluent-schema-registry

I am wondering how i am supposed to use the KafkaAvroSerializer. I have installed the confluent-schema-registry as a docker container.

Downloading the sources of the schema registry and building it locally does not work because all the dependencies are missing in maven central and i would have to build them myself als well (**i cannot believe that this is the intended way of getting the serializer libraries for production purposes**).

The only workaround i found is going into the docker container crawling through the file system searching for the confluent artifacts and cping it my way back to where i need them. **icannot believe that this is the intended way either**.

- *What is the intended way of getting the serializer library? Am is overseeing the obvious?*
- *Why is it not available via maven central, it would be so easy?!*

Comment: Confluent's artifacts are available from [Confluent's Maven repository](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/install.html#java).

Comment: Thanks, and how can i find out the artefacts available?

Answer (score 0):

The following is an index link with all the versions of kafka-avro-serializer library:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.confluent/kafka-avro-serializer?repo=confluent-packages

If you click on a version, you see a page with the artifact declaration that you need to add to your `pom.xml`.

In that page there is also a section **"Repositories"** with a link next to it named: ["Confluent"](https://packages.confluent.io/maven/). Click on it and it will take you to a page that shows you the url that you need to include to your `pom.xml` or to corresponding `settings.xml` for accessing the specific artifact. e.g. like this:

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>confluent</id>
        <url>http://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```